# How to Write data directly to mounted volume in linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, storage, mount, nessus

I have an application running in the / system of a cloud vm. (dev/sda)
I can't resize the root "/ "partition to extend the storage size and the application does not have an option to write the reports to a different location.

So I have created another hard disk /dev/sdb and attached it to the vm.

I have created an fstab entry like the one below...
but
the issue now is that the application is still writing data to /dev/sda instead of /dev/sdb.

How to fix this? I want to be able to write data directly to the mount point which is /datadrive on /dev/sdb instead of /dev/sda

```
UUID=exxxxxx-fxxx-4xxx-bxxx-7xxxxxxxxxxx      /datadrive xfs  defaults,nofail 1 2
/opt/application/var/users/user1/reports/  /datadrive/application-reports/user1/reports/ none bind
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mounting it the wrong way around.

Your bind mount should be from /datadrive to /opt

So like this:

```
UUID=xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx     /datadrive xfs  defaults,nofail 1 2
/datadrive/application-reports/user1/reports/ /opt/application/var/users/user1/reports  none bind
```